# I get a fatal error for a query who select data from my db, may be for syntax

Tags: php, sql, syntax

Is something wrong with the syntax of this query? I'm using mysql and PHP.

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT denominazione 
                        FROM tab02_impianti 
                        WHERE tab02_impianti.cod_impianto = tab05_workgroup.cod_impianto 
                        AND tab05_workgroup.cod_utente = tab01_utenti.cod_utente ");
```

Because I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in...

The error show up because of the WHERE sentence. It works without it but I get all the data of the table. So this part: "SELECT denominazione FROM tab02_impianti" should be ok.

I cant figure it out, can I get some help please? Thank you very much :)

Let me write something more:
I have users table (tab01) and industrial installations (tab02). Every user can be related to more installations and vice versa. 
The tab05, workgroup, contain the id of both. I just want to show to the user the information about the industrial installations that he is allowed to.

Comment: Run that query in phpMyAdmin and if there is an error it will tell you about it.

Comment: _Alternatively add some_ **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: You could also make code easier to read and easier to writer if you removed the table numbers part of each tables name and just gave the table a sensible name

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is caused by `fetch()` function because your `query()` function returns false.

The false boolean is return on your `query()` function because there is an error somewhere on it. To help you debugging your query, you can check for error case :

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT denominazione FROM tab02_impianti WHERE tab02_impianti.cod_impianto = tab05_workgroup.cod_impianto AND tab05_workgroup.cod_utente = tab01_utenti.cod_utente ");

//error case
if(!$stmt)
{
  die("Execute query error, because: ". print_r($conn->errorInfo(),true) );
}
//success case
else{
     //continue flow
}
```